# Package acceptance validation error: Couldn't find external file reference

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have a Windows 10 App in the Microsoft-Store. This project exists for a while now and is in an Azure DevOps hosted.

Recently I fixed some bugs. The App works fine and gets a green PASSED from the *Windows App Certification Kit*

When I upload the .appxupload, I get the following error messages:

> You must provide a package that supports each selected device family
>   (or uncheck the box for unsupported device families). Note that
>   targeting the Xbox device family requires a neutral or x64 package.
>
> You must upload at least one package. If you are using market groups,
>   then each market group must have at least one package.
>
> You must fix all package validation errors before submitting.
>   MyProject.App_1.0.5.0_x86_x64_bundle.appxupload 25.7 MB
>
> Package acceptance validation error: We encountered a fatal error
>   while parsing the package MyProject.App_1.0.5.0_x86_x64.appxbundle:
>   Couldn't find external file reference 'MyProject.App_1.0.5.0_x86.appx'
>   with full name: '36813MyCompany.MyProject_1.0.5.0_x86__0aac093vbbdv0'.
>   Try again or upload a new package.

The App is associated with the store and the settings in the Package.appxmanifest are set to the product identity from the store.

The App package gets build for x86 and x64. No other architectures.

What do I forget / wrong, when building the package?

Comment: Does your app support Xbox platform?

Comment: No, the app targets desktop only.

Comment: Please uncheck xbox device support in uwp dev center when submit your package.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try the following:

1. Rename your current .appxupload file to have a .zip extension.  Unzip its contents.
2. Rename one of your **last successful** .appxupload files to have a .zip extension.  Unzip its contents.
3. Compare the contents of both .zip files.  Do they both contain the same files?

Next, inside the above .zip file, you will see a file with an extension of  .appxbundle.  Rename this file to have a .zip extension, and unzip it.   Do these contents match the older .appxbundle contents.  Do you see a .appx for x64 and x86?  Try double-clicking on one of these files to ensure that Windows asks if you want to install this file.

If you don't see these .appx files, you probably forgot to check some checkboxes when you were generating the store packages.

If that doesn't help, I would suggest you check for changes in your package.appmanifest between your last successful store upload and your current store upload.  Hopefully, you're using some kind of revision control system (e.g. Git) that let's you see the changes.

If that doesn't work, I would try rebuilding the .appxupload after cleaning up all old files.  In Visual Studio, right click on your solution and choose "Clean".  Then, close Visual Studio, and manually delete all "bin" and "obj" directories.  Then, run Visual Studio, make sure you are building "Release", and re-create the .appxupload package, and try again.

You might also want to check to make sure the app isn't already installed on your system before building and deploying. Type your app's name into the Windows search bar.  If the app shows up, right click on it, and choose "Uninstall".  Wait a few seconds (for full uninstall), and then try rebuilding your .appxupload package.

Finally, when creating the .appxupload, I would suggest carefully watching Visual Studio's "Output" window for any warnings or errors.

Comment: I don't have an old package ready to compare, but the new one does not contain a .appxsym file.

Comment: I have updated my answer above with some additional instructions.  Unzip the .appxbundle, and make sure you see the .appx files in there.

Comment: Appxfiles were present. What solved the issue, was removing all Store information, commit and Push.  Delete from disk, checkout and connect to the store again. Upload Successful.